# ng2-charts fails on ng serve

Tags: angular

[this is error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9pkZ.png)

[image]

I get the above error when starting Angular project using ng serve,this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "echarts": "^3.2.0",
    "echarts-ng2": "^5.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng2-echarts": "0.0.3",
    "ngx-echarts": "^1.2.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "systemjs": "^6.1.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears `ng2-charts` is incompatible with your version of Typescript, which is most likely a dependency of your version of Angular. You will want to make sure that package is compatible with Angular 4.x.

Comment: as Drew said, that package was last publish 3 years ago, so big possibility is not compatible with your angular version

Comment: It was an old project, and I wanted to redeploy it,so i try rebuilding the old environment from package.json files, but I ran into a lot of problems，Because I'm not familiar with Angular,Some environments cannot be restored,but it is vevy important for me.

Comment: I try to update the version of Typescript,but the same mistake

Comment: @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.7 requires typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' but 3.7.2 was found instead.
      Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

         npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'

         To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".

Comment: Oh, you need to delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` to reinstall the dependencies from the project and make sure your environment doesn't used the cached dependencies are most likely still saved in your package-lock.json file.

Comment: Thanks,I'm try to update the @angular/cli  version to 1.2.7 and delete node_modules and package-lock.json and run npm install ,Now  i can run it ,i think t the reason may be wrong version of  @angular/cli,beacause Its original running environment was V1.2.7,I mistakenly thought 1.4.10 was compatible with 1.2.7.